# How can i parse H264 file and frames

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, h.264

An H264 file is a stream of NAL (Network Abstraction Layer) units, each encoding a frame (I, B, or P). What is the best way to parse this file and to extract sizes and detect ends of each NAL unit in the file, as well as detect the type of frame the NAL unit contains?

Comment: You can use Media Foundation if your platform is Vista and above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx there are sample apps in the SDK

Comment: if you ever return can you accept the other answer so I can delete mine

Comment: This question is perfectly focused and is asking a solution to one single problem: how to parse an h264 file as a stream of NAL units. Folks should not close questions that reside outside their knowledge domain.

Answer (score 23):

If you're not actually trying to decode the frames, you can write a simple 'parser' by reading the h.264 byte stream and looking for NAL unit signature.

Here's what you need to know:

- NAL Units start code: 00 00 01 X Y
- X = IDR Picture NAL Units (e.g 25, 45, 65)
- Y = Non IDR Picture NAL Units (e.g. 01, 21, 41, 61)

So, if you find 3 bytes [00 00 01] in sequence, very likely it's the beginning of the NAL unit. Then you will need to parse the the next two bytes [X Y] to find out the type of frame. Please refer to the [spec](http://www-ee.uta.edu/dip/courses/ee5356/H264systems.pdf) for more details.

Comment: The link to the spec is a 404...

Comment: 9 years is a long time, @PeterHansen

Comment: Only a year and a half later than your latest comment on the question @GeorgeSkoptsov. ;-)

Comment: The broken link can be recovered at https://web.archive.org/web/20170403144107/http://www-ee.uta.edu/dip/courses/ee5356/H264systems.pdf