# How to identify frames in h264 video stream over UDP

Tags: video, udp, h.264

Please provide me some help to find out the frames in h264 video that is streamed over UDP.

I have streamed the video file from VLC player in to a port(localhost:1246) and written a UDP socket program in C to write the stream from UDP port to a binary file(test.bin) in local folder.

Now my question is how to fetch the frames(I/P/B) from this data. Please help me to resolve this

Regards,
Spk

Answer (score 1):

Atlast i got the answer after a few research.

We can identify the frames in NAL packets of h264 stream via

•   NAL Units start code: 00 00 01 X Y
•   X = IDR Picture NAL Units (25, 45, 65)
•   Y = Non IDR Picture NAL Units (01, 21, 41, 61) ; 01 = b-frames, 41 = p-frames

Reference : [How can i parse H264 file and frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123544/how-can-i-parse-h264-file-and-frames)

Regards,
Suku PK

Answer (score 0):

The H.264 data streamed over UDP is likely to be

- [RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184) compatible stream -- where you need to check the data against this specification for further splitting into frames
- raw H.264 stream where you are supposed to detect NAL units per [H.264 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264)

Comment: With the data being streamed over UDP is it possible for the NAL units to be spread out over multiple datagrams? If so how would that be dealt with?

Comment: @ddelnano: Yes, it can be both ways: small NALs can be combined to fit one datagram and vice versa large NAL can be split into parts. RFC link above explains the respective formatting.

Comment: If I am using VLC to stream the H.264 over UDP unicast would that mean that my stream would be raw H.264 or does that not necessarily guarantee that? I see in VLC there is an RTP option but I am not using that.  Sorry if that does not make sense I just got started learning about H.264 and struggling to implement a live camera feed so far.

Comment: @ddelnano: there is no way to stream raw elementary H.264 stream over UDP reliably: no delivery guarantee, possibly out of order transmission and small datagrams make it impossible to reconstruct the feed reliably on receiving side. This is the reason why additional effort such as RTP is here: to still be able to use UDP as carrier, and be able to re-create the feed afterwards. RTP is also great option because it's well documented.